# extracting text from mangled html tag with <br> separating the elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

So I have this html piece:

```
<p class="tbtx">


                              MWF



<br></br>

TH
</p>
```

which is completely mangled it seems. I need to extract the data i.e. ['MWF', 'TH'].

The only solution I could think of is to replace all newlines and spaces in the html, then split it at 
 and rebuild html structure and then extract .text but it's a bit ridiculous.

Any proper solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) is what you are looking for - it removes unneccessary whitespace and returns the strings.

Demo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<p class="tbtx">


                              MWF



<br></br>

TH
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print list(soup.stripped_strings)  # prints [u'MWF', u'TH']
```

Comment: People should notice that it doesn't work with all versions of BeautifulSoup. Worked for me only after I've installed BeautifulSoup4

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and BeautifulSoup to pull out just the text from your HTML snippet.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p class="tbtx">


                              MWF



<br></br>

TH
</p>"""

print filter(None,BeautifulSoup(html).get_text().strip().split("\n"))
```

Outputs:

```
[u'MWF', u'TH']
```

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend extracting text using Regular Expressions

For instance if your html was as you noted:

```
"
<p class="tbtx">


                              MWF



<br></br>

TH
</p>
"
```

We can see that the desired text ("MWF","TH") is surround by whitespace characters.

Thus the regular expression("\s\w+\s") reads "find any set of word characters that are  surrounded by white space characters" and would identify the desired text.

Here is a cheat sheet for creating Regular Expressions: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

And you can test your Regular Expression on desired text here: http://regexpal.com/